# Richardson Extrapolation on forward differencing formula

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, numerical-calculus, extrapolation

After deriving this with forward differencing formula & Taylor series:

$$ D_1 f = f'(x_{i}) = \frac{f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_{i})}{h} - \frac{f''(x_{i})h}{2!} $$

which could perhaps also be written as:

$$\tag 1 f'(x) \approx \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

I need to apply Richardson Extrapolation to it to find a formula with a smaller error value. From the tutorials I have seen, i understand that I need to use central differnecing formula but I am unable to understand how as the examples I have seen online are quite different.

The next step that I could think of was this:

$$\tag 2 f'(x) \approx 2\dfrac{f(x+h/2)-f(x)}{h}$$

but I don't know how to proceed.

Could explain step by step or give reference to a relevant example?

Answer (score 1):

You have a formula for approximating $f'(x)$ with step-size $h$:
$$ f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+Kh+O(h^2)=[f](h)+Kh+O(h^2)$$
where $K$ is some constant (all we are saying is that the error is proportional to $h$ and has higher-order terms) and I've used $[f](h)$ to mean $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$. Now we also have,

$$ f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h/2)-f(x)}{h/2}+\frac{Kh}{2}+O(h^2)=[f]\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)+\frac{Kh}{2}+O(h^2) $$
and so we can combine $[f](h)$ and $[f](h/2)$ to eliminate the $Kh$ terms:
$$\begin{align*}-f(x)+2f'(x)&=-\left([f](h)+Kh+O(h^2)\right)+2\left([f](h/2)+\frac{Kh}{2}+O(h^2)\right) \\
f'(x)&=2[f]\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)-[f](h)+O(h^2)
\end{align*} $$
so
$$2[f]\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)-[f](h)=4\frac{f(x+h/2)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{-f(x+h)+4f(x+h/2)-3f(x)}{h}$$
is an $O(h^2)$ approximation to $f'(x)$.